# How can i call a JFrame from a class?

Tags: java, swing, constructor, default-package

I have an project which have a Jframe under a default package.I cant call the jframe from a another main class .

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("         Hello");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

another class is : A.java

```
package a;



/**
 *
 * @author Anupom
 */
public class A {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: to much autogenerated code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any errors ? if so - State the here so we can see

Also on the 'other' class just do this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJFrame frame = new NewJFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also on your JFrame class instead of

```
... extends javax.swing.JFrame

just do 

extends JFrame
```

And then you will be able to add import at the top of this class

```
import javax.swing*;
```

And as a result all method that are used by swing in your code wont have to have this javax.swing (pre-annotation  is that correct term? )

you don't need all that auto generated crap ;)

EDIT: Slightly cleaner solution for you :)

```
import javax.swing*;

public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {
    private JLabel jLabel1;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("         Hello");

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {        
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```